# Finding the largest argument of a function subject to a bound

Tags: r, optimization

As the title suggests, I would like to solve the following problem. Let f denote a a certain function and let f0 denote a given constant. Is there an economical way of finding `max{x:f(x) <= f0}`?

Here is what an example would look like:

```
f = function(x) (x-2)^2
f0 = 0.4
```

and in that case the correct answer would be about 2.5. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post what you've tried.  SO isn't a coding writing service.

Comment: No but it is a question and answer system and there are many new users such as myself who are not so adept at handling such problems. I am not forcing anyone to help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that notation you are using for your constraint, but maybe the `?constrOptim` function can help you?

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for your comment. I am aware of constrOptim but it will not help here as I am looking for the maximum $x$ rather than the maximum of a function and its maximizer.

Comment: Something like `optimize(function(x) {f(x) - f0}, interval = c(-2, 4))`? Note: I have plotted `curve(f(x) - f0, from = -2, to = 4)` first.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks for your input.Yes, I was thinking something along the same lines with (f(x)-f(0))^2 so as to get the zero value as the minimum. It works fine for this case but not that well for more complicated functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility to optimize with constraints would be to define a version of your function `f` which returns `Inf` if the constraint is not met:

```
f <- function(x) (x-2)^2
f0 <- 0.4
f_optim <- function(x, a = f0) ifelse(f(x) <= a, f(x), Inf)

optimize(f_optim, c(-10, 10), a = f0, maximum = T, tol = .Machine$double.eps)
$maximum
[1] 2.632456

$objective
[1] 0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f0 = 0.04
f = function(x) (x - 2)^2

g = function(x, f0) {
  delta = f0 - f(x)
  abs(delta)
}
optimize(g, c(0, 10), f0 = f0, maximum=F, tol= .Machine$double.eps)
```